# Set `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` to a full path

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to export from a large orgmode file a subtree, which looks like this:

```
* Subtree to be exported
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: "C:/PATH/TO/FOLDER/filename.org"
:EXPORT_TITLE:
:END:

foo
```

Error message after C-c C-e C-s h h : »Output file not writable«. How can I add a path to the filename? orgmode 8.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not documented, as far as I can see, it works, but I made two mistakes.

1. Path and name not in "", so no spaces are allowed.
2. Filename without ".org", just the filename without extension.

So this works:

```
* Subtree to be exported
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: C:/PATH/TO/FOLDER/filename
:EXPORT_TITLE:
:END:

foo
```

Comment: Cool! Can each subtree have a different path? I usually export and tangle subtrees after creating an `indirect-buffer` using `C-c` `C-x` `b` and then save the exported buffer.